# Specify environment variable only in release phase

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm attempting to use [Heroku's `"container"` stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) for [Review Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps), but I'm having trouble specifying an environment variable (or config var, in Heroku parlance) that only affects the release phase.

My first attempt was to specify the environment variable under `release.config` key in my `heroku.yml`file:

```yaml
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile.web
    worker: Dockerfile.worker
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - mix ecto.migrate
  config:
    POOL_SIZE: 2
run:
  web:
    command:
      - mix phx.server
  worker:
    command:
      - mix worker
```

However, this resulted in the following build error from Heroku:

```
release.config in body is a forbidden property
```

My subsequent approach was to copy my `Dockerfile.web` to `Dockerfile.release`, specify the environment variable inside `Dockerfile.release` with `ENV POOL_SIZE=2`, and update my `heroku.yml` accordingly:

```yaml
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile.web
    worker: Dockerfile.worker
    release: Dockerfile.release
release:
  command:
    - mix ecto.migrate
run:
  web:
    command:
      - mix phx.server
  worker:
    command:
      - mix worker
```

This resulted in an error that doesn't make very much sense to me:

```
Warning: You have declared both a release process type and a release section. Your release process type will be overridden.=!= Couldn't find the release image configured for this app. Is there a matching run process?
```

Is specifying an environment variable only for the release phase possible with Heroku? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually achieved what I wanted by modifying the `release` section of the `heroku.yml` to this:

```yaml
release:
  command:
    - /usr/bin/env POOL_SIZE=2 mix ecto.migrate
```

I believe that if the `ENTRYPOINT` in my Dockerfile had been `/usr/bin/env`, that part could probably be left off.

Circling back to the separate Dockerfile approach (which I ultimately had to switch to for an unrelated reason), the fix there is to change the `CMD` in `Dockerfile.release` to `mix ecto.migrate` and remove the `release` section of the `heroku.yml` file.